# $M_3$ is modular

Tags: solution-verification, lattice-orders

I was checking if $M_3$ and $N_5$ are modular.
[image: Diamond and Pentagon lattices]
So first is pentagon lattice. I am checking whether $a\vee (b\wedge c)=(a\vee b)\wedge c$.

Now for $N_5$, we have $a\le c$. So
$a\vee(b\wedge c)=a\vee 0=a$ and $(a\vee b)\wedge c=1\wedge c=c$.

So $a\vee (b\wedge c)\ne (a\vee b)\wedge c$ and hence $N_5$ is not modular.

But $a,b,c$ are pairwise incomparable in $M_3$. Means no $a\le c$. So how can $M_3$ be modular?

I know I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for any help.

Comment: In $M_3$, we have $0 < a, b, c < 1$, so there are comparable pairs. But for all these the implication is trivial. If you take just the middle elements, then the implication is vacuously true, meaning that it is true just because the antecedent is never satisfied.

Comment: can we say $0<a,b,c<1$ mean $a,b,c$ are comparable?

Comment: No, each of them is comparable both with $0$ and $1$, quite trivially...

Comment: so if we have to prove that $M_3$ is modular, we need to check $0\le a$ or $a\le 1$? can't we perform this with each $a,b,c$ in each possible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use different letters for the variables.

We need to verify $x\lor(y\land z)=(x\lor y)\land z$ whenever $x,y,z\in M_3$ and $x\le z$.

You can easily check that the identity holds in any lattice if any two of $x,y,z$ coincide, or if $x=0$ or $z=1$.

Since in $M_3$ all the comparable pairs $x\le z$ with $x\ne z$ include either $0$ or $1$, indeed *there's nothing else to check*.

Comment: thanks for your response. my question actually was that by definition, $L$ is modular if $x\le y\implies x\vee (y\wedge z)=(x\vee y)\wedge z$ holds. But in $M_3$, this isn't happening because any two elements other than $0$ and $1$ are incomparable. So how is it happening?

Comment: Well, yes, you will either have $x=z$ or $x=0$ or $z=1$ if $L=N_5$ and $x\le z$. Those cases are still valid.

Comment: I'm takling about $M_3$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, wrote the wrong one. I also updated my answer.